# Tight_Layout: Attribute Error . 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'tight_layout'

Tags: python, matplotlib, layout, label, attributeerror

I want to plot a stacked-bar graph with data coming from two separate dataframes in pandas (My_means and My_stds). I am using Python 3.7.

The plotting call works fine, however, the labels are cut-off. Setting tight_layout does not help me and generates an "Attribute Error: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'tight_layout'". What does this mean and how do I overcome this?

I haven´t found any problems related to this error, so I assume I am doing something rather stupid...

Here is my code:

```
My_means= ratios.pivot_table('Data', 'Sample ID', 'User ID', aggfunc= np.mean)
My_stds= ratios.pivot_table('Data', 'Sample ID', 'User ID', aggfunc= np.std)
plot_it = My_means.plot(kind='bar', color=stack_cols, stacked=True, yerr=My_stds, capsize=3, title='Just some graph')
plot_it.tight_layout()
```

Thanks for your help! 
Jazz

Comment: You can't apply `tight_layout` on an axes, you ned to do it on a figure. Most often done using `plt.tight_layout()`

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the quick reply. I thought the way I do it, plot_it would be my figure. However, it seems that it isnt... (new to coding, sorry). How can I get it as my figure object so that tight_layout would work for me?

Comment: `plot_it` is the axes, not the figure. If you have done `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` then you can simply do `plt.tight_layout()`

Comment: It works fine! Thanks for you help. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`My_means.plot(…)` returns an axes object. Whereas `tight_layout` requires a figure object. There are a number of different approaches you can use:

Perhaps the simplest one would be to use `plt.tight_layout()` which works on the current figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Your plotting code here
plt.tight_layout()
```

Alternatively, you can create the figure and axes beforehand, pass the axes as an argument to `plot` and then use `tight_layout` on the figure object:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_it = My_means.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, …)

fig.tight_layout()
```